# Stacking/concatenating tensors increases memory usage

Tags: pytorch

In PyTorch, I found `stack`-ing or `cat`-ing multiple tensors would increase memory usage by the sum of the sizes of all these arrays. An example is as follows:

```
import torch as tc
import torch.autograd as tag
import sys
import psutil
import os
import resource

def get_ru_maxrss():
    """ Return max RSS usage (in kilobytes) """
    size = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        # on Mac OS X ru_maxrss is in bytes, on Linux it is in KB
        size //= 1024
    return size / 1024

def cpuStats():
        print(sys.version)
        print(psutil.cpu_percent())
        print(psutil.virtual_memory())  # physical memory usage
        pid = os.getpid()
        py = psutil.Process(pid)
        memoryUse = py.memory_info()[0] / 2. ** 30  # memory use in GB...I think
        print('memory GB:', memoryUse)

m0 = get_ru_maxrss()

x1 = tc.ones([8192, 8192], requires_grad=True)
print(x1.dtype)
print(get_ru_maxrss() - m0)
print('=======')

y = x1 * 1.1
print(y.dtype)
print(get_ru_maxrss() - m0)
print('=======')

for i in range(10):
    y = tc.cat([y, x1])
    print(y.dtype)
    print(get_ru_maxrss() - m0)
    print('=======')

loss = tc.mean(y)

print(get_ru_maxrss() - m0)
print('=======')

loss.backward()

print(get_ru_maxrss() - m0)
print('=======')
```

And we can see that each occurence of `cat` in the for loop increases memory usage by 512 MB, which is the sum of `y` and `x1` (256 MB each). This isn't a major issue for me right now but I'm just curious about it. If I understand it correctly, the vector-Jacobian product of stack or concatenation is just to perform the reversed operation to the gradient vector, splitting it back into multiple arrays whose shapes match the original inputs to the stack or cat function. This process doesn't need the intermediate value of the stacked tensor computed in the forward pass, which is similar to a linear operation, but the latter doesn't incur additional memory usage (e.g., if I change the `cat` in the for loop to a linear op such as `y = y * 1.1`, it won't increase memory consumption). So I'm wondering if the increased memory usage is essentially just an empty space allocated to hold the ``splitted'' gradient arrays in the backward pass, which has to be contiguous, so the splitting operation doesn't have to stride in memory? It follows that a linear operation doesn't need this additional memory because the memory space of the input gradient can be directly overwritten without worrying about memory contiguity. Is that right?